# Is it possible to print non-printing characters with a %C specifier?

Tags: c

Is it possible to use a function to detect non-printing characters with `isctrl()` and use printf with %C specifier to print them as '\n' for instance?

Or I should write an `if` for every control caracter and `printf("\\n")` for instance..?

OK, thanks to All of the kind people below - it is not posible, you HAVE to specify each situation. example:

```
if (isctrl(char))// WRONG
 printf("%c", char);

if (char == '\n')//RIGHT, or using switch. 
 printf("\\n");
```

Comment: Well, it's probably better to use [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) to detect printable characters, instead of using `isctrl` which might return false positives (as there are non-printable characters that are not control characters).

Comment: @nhahtdh It does make some sense - though I wouldn't find it useful, that is. OP wants to see `\n` on the screen instead of a line break... If there is no built in or other preexisting solution for this, I'd recommend a `switch-case` construct for it, much nicer than an endless if-else...

Comment: @ppeterka: The wording confuse me a bit there. It makes sense after reading your comment.

Comment: Note `%C` and `%c` are not the same. `%C` would be used for a *wide* character. Which are you asking about?

Comment: thanks allot for the help. I edited the question with the conclusion. please correct me if im wrong @ppeterka

Comment: @Nir accept an answer mate That's SO's way of thanking :-)

Comment: @Aniket you right, forgot to do that ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To expand on the answer by Aniket, you could use a combination of [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) and the switch-statement solution:

```
char ch = ...;

if (isprint(ch))
    fputc(ch, stdout);  /* Printable character, print it directly */
else
{
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '\n':
        printf("\\n");
        break;

    ...

    default:
        /* A character we don't know, print it's hexadecimal value */
        printf("\\x%02x", ch);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one question mate, why check `isprint()` when we know which characters are _not_ printable characters, and put them inside the switch anyway? .. just curious.

Comment: @Aniket Because in 7-bit ASCI there are 32 unprintable "characters", you would need a case for each of them. Then we of course have the other characters in the 8-bit character set, which also have unprintable characters. That's a _lot_ of cases if you want to take care of all of them. Using `isprint` you only need to have cases for the unprintable characters you are interested in. Of course, the check could be done in the `default` case instead of doing it before the `switch` like I do.

Answer (score 11):

```
const char *pstr = "this \t has \v control \n characters";
char *str = pstr;
while(*str){
   switch(*str){
     case '\v': printf("\\v");break;
     case '\n': printf("\\n"); break;
     case '\t': printf("\\t"); break;
     ...
     default: putchar(*str);break;
   }
   str++;
}
```

this will print the non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the non-printing character, but  i dont think so, you can write those characters.
You can detect specific non printing characters by observing their ASCII value.